# Getting SmartArt objects using Aspose.Cells (.NET)

Tags: .net, aspose

I need to access to SmartArt objects in Excel Worksheet. I'm using Aspose Total for .NET to parse excel files. While other types like shapes, textboxes are accesible directly on Worksheet, the smartArt objects are not (or I cannot find them). Is there a way how to get SmartArt objects (by using Aspose)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid this feature is unavailable in Aspose (yet). See posts [here](http://www.aspose.com/community/forums/permalink/492413/443813/showthread.aspx) or [here](http://www.aspose.com/community/forums/permalink/475851/475851/showthread.aspx)

Comment: You are right. I have asked on Aspose forum and it really looks like this feature is not implemented. Thank you anyway